# ocaml bubble sort

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

My basic idea is to implement a bubble sort of type `('a list -> 'a list)`. I use variables which are `sorted` and `result`. If I change some of elements in the list, `sorted` becomes 1. Otherwise, `sorted` remains 0. `Result` is one cycle of the comparison.

I think there is something wrong with my `sorted` variable. Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

```
let rec sort (l: int list) : int list =
    let sorted=0 in
    let result = match l with
           | []->[]
           | x::xs-> if xs=[] then x
                     else let y::ys = xs in
                          if x<y then x::sort(xs)
                          else let sorted=1 in
                               y::sort(x::ys)
    in
    if sorted=0 then result
    else sort(result)
```

Comment: so you are sorting the list, and if that sorting did not change anything, you want to return the original, otherwise you want to sort it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you're trying to use `sorted` as a mutable variable. OCaml variables are immutable. Once you bind a variable to a value, the binding can't be changed. Each of your `let sorted =` statements defines a *new* variable named `sorted`. So your last test will always show sorted to be equal to 0. It is testing the first definition of sorted, which can never have any other value than 0.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. Your explanation is so clear! By the way, is there any way to implement some "flag value" in OCaml?

Comment: You can create mutable values (not variables) in OCaml. But if you're new to OCaml you should learn to work with immutable values first. It's enlightening and surprisingly effective (which is one reason OCaml is often chosen as a language to study).

Comment: (The key insight is that function parameters can be different from one call to another. You can make any value that might change during the computation into a parameter of the computation, and call your computation repeatedly. The repeated calls can be recursive calls. Or they can be driven by a higher-order function like a fold.)

Answer (score 1):

As Jeffrey said, OCaml values are immutable. That is why your program does not work as expected.

But there are other problems with your code:

- `sorted` should have type `bool`, not `int`. One the pros of OCaml is that it has a strong type system, so use it.
- To deconstruct list, you should use pattern matching only `if xs=[] then x else let y::ys = xs in` is not not the good way of doing it (and OCaml should warn you that your pattern matching is not exhaustive). You should add other cases to your pattern matching instead.

Like this:

```
| [] -> []
| x::[] -> x
| x::y::ys -> ...
```